# Converting list with json dumps returns string instead of data dictionary

Tags: python, json

I am trying to get json data from Request URL using requests. Result I get is string so first I use json loads to convert it to list and after that I use json dumps to convert it to data dictionary. But instead I get string again. I would like to get it as data dictionary.

This is the code I use:

```
from json import loads
import json


url = 'https://www.sberbank.hr/umbraco/api/ExchangeRates/GetRates?dateString=1633159401811'

data = requests.get(url).json()


jsondata = loads(data)

print(type(jsondata))

data_dict = json.dumps(jsondata)

print(type(data_dict))
```

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here.  `jsondata = loads(data)` makes `jsondata` a Python data structure. You work with that directly. This: `data_dict = json.dumps(jsondata)` turns the Python data structure *back into a string* that you can *write to a file*. So it *reverses* the effect of  `jsondata = loads(data)` . That string will be valid JSON and that is what you need to send your modified data to another program.

Comment: The result is a list of dictionaries you can use a for loop to access the elements.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It works exactly like how it described in the document: https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.dumps

I think your jsondata is already an array of objects, what are you trying to archive here?

Answer (score 0):

When you use `json.loads`, it converts thejson string to a `dict` type and `json.dumps` converts `dict` to json string.
Just use `json.loads` if you want a dict.

I've inspected the data you are using. The structure is:

```
List[Dict]
```

So you can acess it like this `data[0]` or any index.